# How can I get the PowerShell ISE to do syntax highlighting on files with a custom extension?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I'd like to start using a custom extension for some of my Powershell scripts, but when I drag them into the PowerShell ISE, they are treated as plaintext, and I don't get any syntax highlighting.  Is there anything I can do to get the ISE to recognize my custom file extension as a PowerShell script?

Comment: I would like to know this too.  But I have a feeling we will have to wait for MS to fix this.

Comment: Side note: found this question after all my syntax highlighting was green but that was cause I was using the "monochrome green" theme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Can't be done** because, as of the current version, the ISE determines whether to turn syntax highlighting on or not based on the file name extension: this behavior can't be changed as the recognized extensions are (unfortunately) fixed in the code.

They are, of course:

- .ps1
- .psm1
- .psd1

For those who are wondering, the ISE determines this within the `IsPowerShellSourceCodeFile` internal property of the `Microsoft.PowerShell.Host.ISE.ISEFile` type, exported by the `Microsoft.PowerShell.GPowerShell` assembly. And no, reflection does not allow to cheat it, as trying to inject one of the supported extensions into the `Extension` property causes the ISE to crash.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say this is possible.  The Powershell module [here](http://sqlpsx.codeplex.com/documentation) brings SQL highlighting to the Powershell ISE.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the PS script file extension was inadvertently `.ps`, when I renamed it to have `.ps1` extension, all the syntax highlighting revived.  Hope this helps others.

Comment: This advice appears to already be stated in the accepted answer.